# maya kBeforeSave callback

Tags: python, api, maya

I need to register to some maya's MSceneMessage callback, and query the scene paths. I need to get both before and after's maya path. (open , save file)

Here's what I have so far.

```
def before(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'BEFORE: ' + cmds.file(query = True)

def after(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'AFTER: ' + cmds.file(query = True)

om.MSceneMessage.addCallback(om.MSceneMessage.kBeforeOpen, before)
om.MSceneMessage.addCallback(om.MSceneMessage.kAfterOpen, after)

om.MSceneMessage.addCallback(om.MSceneMessage.kBeforeSave, before)
om.MSceneMessage.addCallback(om.MSceneMessage.kAfterSave, after)
```

Case scenario1; In scene test_01.ma, OPEN scene test_02.ma

Works as expected.

BEFORE: ../../test_01.ma

AFTER: ../../test_02.ma

Case scenario2; In scene test_01.ma, SAVE scene test_02.ma

**DOESN'T work as expected.**

**BEFORE: ../../test_02.ma**

AFTER: ../../test_02.ma

I also tried 'kBeforeSaveCheck' callback, with same result.

Comment: i am astonished, what the query result would be(except RuntimeError :: flag can not be queried!!), what is the information that you wanna query, scenename? incl. path?

Answer (score -1):

## get the [scenename](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/file.html)

```
def scene_id(*args):
    return cmds.file(query=True, scenename=True)

def before(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'BEFORE: {0}'.format(scene_id())

def after(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'After: {0}'.format(scene_id())
```